# Having a problem with my javascript code - computer has to guess the digit value I input

Tags: javascript

First I created a version of this which worked where I didn't input the value on the webpage:

```
        <p>Enter in how many fingers (between 0 and 5) you are holding up: </p>

        <p>
            <input id="fingersInput" type="text">
            <button id="fingersSubmit">Guess!</button>
        </p>

        <div id="fingers-game-v2"></div>

        <p id="computer-guess-results"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var numberOfFingers = document.getElementById("fingersInput").value;

            var fingersText = "";

            var correctGuesses = 0;  

            i = 0;

             while (i < 5)
                {
                    var computerGuess = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);

                    fingersText += "<p>" + computerGuess + "</p>";

                    if (computerGuess == 3)
                            {
                             var correctGuesses = correctGuesses + 1;
                            }

                    i++;
                }

            document.getElementById("fingers-game-v2").innerHTML = fingersText;

            document.getElementById("computer-guess-results").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "Number of times the computer guessed correctly: " + "</h3>" + correctGuesses; 

        </script>
```

Then this is the version I'm trying to create where I enter in the input on the webpage, and then the computer tries to guess it, but it's not executing at all or showing anything when I try to debug in the console.

```
        <p>Enter in how many fingers (between 0 and 5) you are holding up: </p>

        <p>
            <input id="fingersInput" type="text">
            <button id="fingersSubmit">Guess!</button>
        </p>

        <div id="fingers-game-v2"></div>

        <p id="computer-guess-results"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var numberOfFingers = document.getElementById("fingersInput").value;

            var fingersText = "";

            var correctGuesses = 0;  

            document.getElementById("fingersSubmit").onclick = function ()
                {
                i = 0;

                while (i < 5)
                    {
                        var computerGuess = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);

                        fingersText += "<p>" + computerGuess + "</p>";

                        if (computerGuess == numberOfFingers)
                            {
                                var correctGuesses = correctGuesses + 1;
                            }

                        i++;
                    }

                document.getElementById("fingers-game-v2").innerHTML = fingersText;

                document.getElementById("computer-guess-results").innerHTML = "<h3>" + "Number of times the computer guessed correctly: " + "</h3>" + correctGuesses; 
                }
```

I'm a beginner coder so if there is any useful knowledge pertaining to this in addition to showing me the correct code, then I'd greatly appreciate that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version where I tried to stay as close to your original code as possible:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Enter in how many fingers (between 0 and 5) you are holding up:</p>

    <p>
      <input id="fingersInput" type="text" />
      <button id="fingersSubmit">Guess!</button>
    </p>

    <div id="fingers-game-v2"></div>

    <p id="computer-guess-results"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('fingersSubmit').onclick = function() {
        i = 0;
        var fingersText = '';
        var correctGuesses = 0;
        var numberOfFingers = document.getElementById('fingersInput').value;

        while (i < 5) {
          var computerGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

          fingersText += '<p>' + computerGuess + '</p>';

          if (computerGuess == numberOfFingers) {
            correctGuesses = correctGuesses + 1;
          }

          i++;
        }

        document.getElementById('fingers-game-v2').innerHTML = fingersText;

        document.getElementById('computer-guess-results').innerHTML =
          '<h3>' +
          'Number of times the computer guessed correctly: ' +
          '</h3>' +
          correctGuesses;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main reason your code wasnt working is because you need to get the input value when the button is clicked (i.e. place it inside the onclick)

The other issue is that you redeclare `correctGuesses` inside the if block, so you should just remove the `var` keyword, otherwise you will get NaN

Finally, this isn't strictly a problem with your code, but moving forward you should be aware that `numberOfFingers` is a string whereas `correctGuesses` is a number. In your if block, you compare the two values and it works because you used `==`, which only checks value. It's typically better practice to use `===` which is a stricter equality check, comparing both value and type. So moving forward, you might want to make sure to convert `numberOfFingers` to a number before you do the equality check

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your time! Really appreciate the knowledge about conversion. I'm researching the parseInt() feature now because of that.

However, I made the corrections to the code and it still didn't work. When I put a number in the input and hit the "Guess!" button, nothing happens still.

Comment: Ive edited the answer and included the full html. It should be working (you can test out the snippet to confirm)